# Visual Studio 2010 C++ DLL project - No output DLL file!

Tags: c++, dll

I can compile the DLL project without any error. It says "Build succeeded".
But I don't see any DLL file in the Debug or Release folder.

There are only .exp, .lib and .pdb files

Comment: Can you describe your folder setup for the project, and give any build output from VS?

Comment: By the sound of it, if you say, there's no output DLL, obviously the link step is not working. To confirm, and to save us all guessing, please post the log of the compile output. The link stage I suspect did not happen as no DLL was produced. We're in the dark here. Can you post some more clues...what was the output, what was the compiler output.

Comment: Did you ever find out the problem?  I am experiencing the same thing

Answer (score 40):

Visual Studio 2010 by default puts the output files in `$(SolutionDir)\Debug` or `$(SolutionDir)\Release`. It's quite likely you are looking at Debug and Release folders inside the project - which are the intermediate folders.

To find out where the output files got open Project Properties > General > Output Directory. By default it is `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\` which evaluates to either Debug or Release in your solution directory.

**EDIT** Visual Studio will tell you where it places the output files in the Output window. Just bring it up by going to "View > Output". It'll say something like this:

> 1>  MFCInterop.vcxproj -> C:\temp\sotest\Debug\MFCInterop.dll
>   ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Nope.. I've looked everywhere.  There is no single DLL in the whole project folder (and its subfolders).

Comment: Maybe it sounds obvious, but did you try to rebuild it instead of the general "build" option?

Comment: @prolog, don't look in the *project* folder, look in the *solution* folder.

Comment: Solution directory is normally one level above the project directory. Can you open the output window and have a look at the build log? It'll tell you where the dll goes.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues w/ C# and VB where VS will not create output files. 
The root issue seems to be that it lost its mind w/ respect to a reference.

I trouble shot this way

1. exclude all files
2. adding in a stub class1 file / compile / verify files are created
3. add files back one by one and eventually you can determine what the issue is

   The issue for me was a .Net version mismatch. The reference had a higher version than the project failing

No answer as to why VS does not yield a compile error in this situation.
If I delete the reference altogether , it definitely complains.

greg

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom Show output from:
Change to **Build**
Look in the folder identified.