# Visual C++ 2010 Express doesn't generate DLL file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll

I have a Visual C++ DLL project (just a project, without parent solution) and need to build the DLL.

Build command doesn't generate any error messages. In the Debug folder there is `mylibrary.lib`, but no `mylibrary.dll`.

I looked at [Visual Studio 2010 C++ DLL project - No output DLL file!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816788/visual-studio-2010-c-dll-project-no-output-dll-file), but my case differs from that question. In the build output, there is no message like

> MFCInterop.vcxproj -> C:\temp\sotest\Debug\MFCInterop.dll

only

> MFCInterop.vcxproj -> C:\temp\sotest\Debug\MFCInterop.lib

What can I do in order to generate the DLL file?

Comment: Are you sure you are building DLL? Maybe you set static lib generation in project settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may happen if your DLL does not expose anything.
Normally public API classes of your DLL should be exposed using following construction:

```
#ifdef YOUR_DLL_EXPORTS
    #define YOUR_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define YOUR_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif 

class YOUR_API ClassToExpose {};
```

Then you have to define YOUR_DLL_EXPORTS inside DLL project.
If you don't have exposed stuff DLL is not generated. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

I may be that the dll generated but not in the Debug folder.You should set the output directory for the project.For this go to

> project property--->General--->Output Directory--->.\Debug

Comment: Thank!  For me, the .dll appears in `SolutionDirectory\Debug`, not `SolutionDirectory\ProjectDirectory\Debug` as I expected.